# Replace special characters by equivalent

Tags: string, matlab, replace, diacritics

How do I replace the following special characters by their equivalent?

Vowels: ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú by AEIOUaeiou respectively. And letter Ñ by N.

The expression:

```
str = regexprep(str,'[^a-zA-Z]','');
```

Will remove all characters non in alphabet, but how do I replace with something equivalent like shown above?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a series of regular expressions like:

```
s = regexprep(s,'(?:À|Á|Â|Ã|Ä|Å)','A')
s = regexprep(s,'(?:Ì|Í|Î|Ï)','I')
```

and so on for the rest of the accented characters... (for both upper/lower cases)

Warning: there are so many [variations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) even for the small subset of Latin alphabet

---

A simpler example:

```
chars_old = 'ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú';
chars_new = 'AEIOUaeiou';

str = 'Ámró';
[tf,loc] = ismember(str, chars_old);
str(tf) = chars_new( loc(tf) )
```

The string before:

```
>> str
str =
Ámró
```

after:

```
>> str
str =
Amro
```

Comment: Thanks @Amro, in fact I'm just working with spanish subset, so the special chars are only the shown above. Isn't there a simpler solution? Something like PHP's str_replace where you can pass an array containing the equivalences as an array parameter?

Comment: Another possibility is to use Perl (which is [available](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perl.html) to MATLAB) with modules like [Text::Unidecode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::Unidecode). This is a very powerful solution, which does interesting things like transliteration from Unicode to ASCII. It has been ported to other languages like Python, Java, .. (I have used the Python port in the past)

Comment: @JorgeZapata: I added a simpler example. Each character in `chars_old` is replaced with its equivalent in `chars_new`. You could add the N with the tilde the same way to the list

Answer (score 5):

The following code normalizes all diacritic characters ie ÅÄÖ.

```
function inputWash {
    param(
        [string]$inputString
    )
    [string]$formD = $inputString.Normalize(
            [System.text.NormalizationForm]::FormD
    )
    $stringBuilder = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $formD.Length; $i++){
        $unicodeCategory = [System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo]::GetUnicodeCategory($formD[$i])
        $nonSPacingMark = [System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory]::NonSpacingMark
        if($unicodeCategory -ne $nonSPacingMark){
            $stringBuilder.Append($formD[$i]) | out-null
        }
    }
    $string = $stringBuilder.ToString().Normalize([System.text.NormalizationForm]::FormC)
    return $string.toLower()
}
Write-Host inputWash("ÖÄÅÑÜ");

oaanu
```

Ommit .toLower() if you don't want that feature

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone still needs this... I did, so I took the time to look up all the most common diacritics:

```
function [clean_s] = removediacritics(s)
%REMOVEDIACRITICS Removes diacritics from text.
%   This function removes many common diacritics from strings, such as
%     á - the acute accent
%     à - the grave accent
%     â - the circumflex accent
%     ü - the diaeresis, or trema, or umlaut
%     ñ - the tilde
%     ç - the cedilla
%     å - the ring, or bolle
%     ø - the slash, or solidus, or virgule

% uppercase
s = regexprep(s,'(?:Á|À|Â|Ã|Ä|Å)','A');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:Æ)','AE');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:ß)','ss');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:Ç)','C');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:Ð)','D');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:É|È|Ê|Ë)','E');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:Í|Ì|Î|Ï)','I');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:Ñ)','N');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:Ó|Ò|Ô|Ö|Õ|Ø)','O');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:Œ)','OE');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:Ú|Ù|Û|Ü)','U');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:Ý|Ÿ)','Y');

% lowercase
s = regexprep(s,'(?:á|à|â|ä|ã|å)','a');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:æ)','ae');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:ç)','c');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:ð)','d');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:é|è|ê|ë)','e');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:í|ì|î|ï)','i');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:ñ)','n');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:ó|ò|ô|ö|õ|ø)','o');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:œ)','oe');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:ú|ù|ü|û)','u');
s = regexprep(s,'(?:ý|ÿ)','y');

% return cleaned string
clean_s = s;
end
```

Thanks to Amro for the simple solution!